# DACPAC Deployment setting

Tags: dacpac

I want to publish my dacpac file using VSTS. I will be giving only DACPAC file to Dev ops team. I want to ignore drop table that is not in source. If i Publish it from SSDT, I can change in advanced settings. How to do that for VSTS. I can see an option under debug menu, But I am unable to check that option, Screen shot is attached in below URL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBQPe.png

Answer (score 0):

You can give publish.xml along side your dacpac and include a similar setting in that xml as well such as mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
<TargetDatabaseName>dbname</TargetDatabaseName>
<DeployScriptFileName>dbname.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=<name>;Integrated Security=True;Persist 
Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect 
Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True</TargetConnectionString>
<BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>False</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
<DropObjectsNotInSource>False</DropObjectsNotInSource>
<ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>

</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and while deploying dacpac (using cmd or powershell) you need to pass this xml file path in /Profile: parameter to pick this xml for deployment settings